# Have a string search set up in Matlab, how do I skip a string if none is found?

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

I have some data marked by a set of string markers that start with a 1 for the start, and a 2 for the end row of the data. These strings are a fixed list that I search from. If a string is not found, I want it to skip that string and just give the array a set of 0s as values. The code I use to search and break up the big data sheet into variables based on the markers is below:

```
tasknames = {'task1';'task2';'task3';'task4'};

for n = 1:numel(tasknames) 

    first = find(~cellfun(@isempty,strfind(Text(:,9),[tasknames{n},'_1'])))+1;
    last = find(~cellfun(@isempty, strfind(Text(:,9),[tasknames{n},'_2'])))+1;

    task_data{n} = Data(first:last, :); 
end
```

Basically if `strfnd` comes back empty whne it goes to find that start and end row in Data, it crashes, because non exists. How do I avoid this crash and just fill `task_data{n}` for that particular marker with like 100 zeros or something?

Answer (score 0):

If basically occurs when first and last are empty, meaning you can check it :

```
if(isempty(first)&&isempty(last))

task_data{n}=zeros(1,100);

else

task_data{n}= Data(first:last, :);

end
```